# Stability from Gain and Phase Margin

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

I know that a system with positive gain and phase margin is a stable system. And the one with a negative gain and phase margin is unstable. What will a system with negative phase margin and positive gain margin be ? Stable, Unstable or Marginally stable

Comment: You want both be positive, as far as I know. There are some assumptions in there about the system being minimum phase.

Comment: **1** Try drawing a bode diagram where one of the margins is negative and the other positive. You will see that the resulting shape of the bode diagram is different from most commonly encountered systems (AFAIK). **2** Remember that the first two sentences in your question are applicable only for systems which were open-loop stable to begin with. If you extend the concept of the margins to open-loop unstable systems, you can see systems where the one of the margins is negative, but still the system is stable. **3** I suggest that you include in your question the definitions of the two margins.

Comment: @AJN Concept of margins to open-loop unstable ? Sorry I don't understand. Can you please elaborate more on this ?

Comment: [From the related questions](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/9075) on the sidebar.